# Kotlin wrapper-only classes

Tags: android, kotlin

In my DTO layer, I have many classes that are only wrappers around a list to parse objects like this:

```
{
"items" : [ ...*(list of some DTOs)* ] 
}
```

Is there some Kotlin "magic" how to define that Retrofit returns this kind of types without declaring new classes for each wrapper class?

```
@GET("...")
fun getSomeItems(): Call< *?* >
```

I think I've seen it somewhere, but I can't find it.

Answer (score 1):

You could do something like this:

```
data class Wrapper<T>(val items: List<T>)
```

Then your Retrofit interface would look like:

```
@GET("...")
fun getSomeItems(): Call<Wrapper<ConcreteItemType>>
```

Comment: I wasn't specific enough, items property can be named differently from class to class. 
It could be { "products" : [..] }. {"sellers" : [...] } etc.  
I was hoping maybe that Kotlin has some way to define anonymous type with named properties (so that JsonSerializer knows how to parse those kind of objects)

Comment: Then you probably want to add a custom adapter that captures that and parses the objects the same regardless of the key. This will only work if `products` and `sellers` have the same structure.

Comment: No, they don't have the same structure :( Thank you for your help though.

Comment: If they do not have the same structure then there is not really a way to generalize them. The only think they share with one another is that they contain a list. You might still be able to add an Adapter for the `Wrapper` class.

Comment: Ok, I was hoping I can write something like: 
fun getSomeItems(): Call<object {products:List<Products}> or something similar

Comment: Yeah, you cannot do that. The custom adapter may be able to do this for you, but I am not sure.